# Find Oldest Children-Sibling Process - Kernel - Struct task_struct

Tags: process, kernel

I am writing a system call which should store some info for the process that called it,for its oldest children process and for its oldest sibling process.

I know that the information i want is kept in sched.h in the task_struct and i have managed to store info for the process that called the system call from the fields i wanted from the struct task_struct.

My problem with the oldest children and the oldest sibling is that in the struct task_struct there are two lists which have all the children and all the siblings (if i have understood right).I assume that i have to iterate through those lists and find the last element.But if i find the last element on those lists how can i access their task_struct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This means you have to save the information about **all** the children, because the oldest child dies, and some other becomes the oldest.  So IMHO, you need to focus a bit more on the problem as you don't have a clear idea on what it means being the oldest child process of a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**task_struct** has pointers to youngest child, younger sibling and older sibling. These pointers points to the respective **task_struct** s . `*p_cptr, *p_ysptr, *p_osptr` in task_struct points to youngest child, younger sibling and older sibling respectively. For example `current->p_cptr` simply points to the youngest child,where **current** is the pointer to the **task_struct** of the process currently running.

Comment: What about, oldest child? Is it the same with older sibling? If not, then do I have to traverse through doubly linked list current->children to get it?