# Find oldest child (not sibling) of a process (task_struct)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944717/find-oldest-children-sibling-process-kernel-struct-task-struct) and this [codebase](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/include/linux/sched.h), I know that there are pointers for

1. Youngest child
2. Youngest sibling
3. Oldest sibling.

So with ***Oldest child***, how do I get?

I am thinking of access "children" pointer (current->children) and traverse to the end of that doubly linked list.

Comment: What do you mean with _oldest child?_  Do you mean the one spawned earlier? the one that has more execution time? does it mean counting cpu time (this can be larger than wall clock time elapsed) or how?  should this include the processes that have already `exit(2)`?

Comment: The post you cite has this same problem, it doesn't indicate what is understoo by the oldest process.  In case of a multithreaded processes, two threads of a process can `fork()` simultaneously (in two different processors) and be exactly equal old.  In order to solve a problem, you first to state it in a consistent way.

Comment: Nah, I'm beginner. That's all I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the oldest sibling of the youngest child:

```
current->p_cptr->p_osptr
```